# Bijective String Sorting Transform

Tags: algorithm

I have some difficulty finding the complexity of the **Bijective String Sorting Transform**. Does anybody know the complexity of the transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform and its inverse can be computed in linear time and consuming linear storage. Check out the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3077.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.